# 2-dimensional sublattices with all vectors having very big square (in absolute value)

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, quadratic-forms

QUESTION: Let $\Lambda\times\Lambda\rightarrow {\Bbb Z}$ be a lattice,
that is, ${\Bbb Z}^n$ with a non-degenerate integer quadratic form, not 
definite, not necessarily unimodular, $n>2$. I want to show that for each $N>0$
there exists a 2-dimensional primitive sublattice $\Lambda_0\subset \Lambda$, 
also not definite, such that all nonzero vectors $x\in \Lambda_0$ satisfy $|(x,x)| > N$.

This question is motivated by considering a K3 surface 
(or a hyperkahler manifold) with 2-dimensional Picard
lattice. It is known that the squares of minimal rational
curves are bounded, and we want to find a manifold with
Picard number 2 having no minimal rational curves.

---

**Bounty added** This problem has kept me up late the last two nights, so I'm hoping some of the quadratic form experts will work on it.

I tried to find a strategy working with rational quadratic forms rather than integers, but failed for the following reason:
Equip $\mathbb{Q}^3$ with the quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$. Then I claim that any rank two subspace $L$ on which this form is non-degenerate contains a vector of norm $1$.

Proof: Let $L^{\perp} = \mathbb{Q} v$. Since our form is nondegenerate on $L$, we have $\langle v,v \rangle \neq 0$, say $\langle v,v \rangle = N$, and $\mathbb{Q}^3 = L \oplus \mathbb{Q} v$. Now, $x^2+y^2-z^2$ is equivalent to $N (x')^2 + (y')^2 - N (z')^2$, by the change of variables $(x,y,z) = (\tfrac{N+1}{2} x' + \tfrac{N-1}{2} z', y', \tfrac{N-1}{2} x' + \tfrac{N+1}{2} z')$. So our form is equivalent to $L' \oplus \mathbb{Q} v$, where the form on $L'$ is $(y')^2 - N (z')^2$. By Witt cancellation, the forms on $L$ and $L'$ are equivalent. Since $(y')^2 - N (z')^2$ represents $1$, so does our form on $L$. $\square$

So, when we are trying to construct rank two sub-lattices with no vectors of norm $1$, we have to do so using lattices which do represent $1$ rationally. This seems hard to me...

Comment: seems to me there is a sublattice of dimension $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ on which your nondegenerate form is definite. Does that suffice?

Comment: Sorry! I misstated the question: I should add an assumption that this 2-dimensional lattice is not definite!

Comment: Oh, that probably does demand some kind of diophantine approximation argument, then; I don't quite recall what you commented earlier on the proof you found not really to your liking.

Comment: Presumably you want your lattice not to be a multiple of any other lattice?

Comment: definitely! thanks for pointing this out, I amended the question

Comment: Maybe, we may remove small values of (x,x) using Chinese remainder theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record: OP **Misha Verbitsky** writes that
"[$\Lambda$ of] rank $\geq 6$ or $\geq 7$ is a usual assumption
in these kind of applications", in which case 
Ekaterina Amerik's suggestion of using
$N\cdot H$ (for some fixed indefinite rank-$2$ form $H$)
surely yields the easiest construction;
but there are also primitive indefinite forms $\Lambda_0$ of rank $2$ 
that represent no small nonzero integers of either sign,
and those should work even for $\Lambda$ of rank as small as $3$ 
(as in the lattice that troubled the OP in the first place).

One reasonably simple construction is to take $M>N$ odd and set 
$$
Q(x,y) = \frac1M ((x+My)^2 - (M^4+1)x^2)
= -M^3 x^2 + 2xy + M y^2,
$$
which represents $\pm M$ (as for $(x,y)=(0,1)$ and $(M,M^2-1)$)
but no integer of smaller absolute value other than zero.
This can be checked using the fact that the associated
real quadratic field ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{M^4+1})$ has fundamental unit
$M^2 + \sqrt{M^4+1}$ (of norm $-1$) as small as possible.
Moreover, unlike the forms $N \cdot H$, this $Q$ is primitive,
so any embedding of the into $\Lambda$ of the indefinite lattice 
$\Lambda_0$ associated to $Q$ is automatically primitive as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand whether this is an actual proof or just a sketch? But it definitely seems like the sketch which comes closest to working, and I am supposed to give out the bounty, so I'll give it to you. If this is a actual proof, I'd love to understand how to fill in the gaps. (Why does this $\Lambda$ necessarily embed into $\Lambda_0$, for example?)

Comment: Thanks.  There are two questions here: constructing $\Lambda_0$
and proving it embeds into $\Lambda$.  (Not $\Lambda$ into $\Lambda_0$, right?)
The former I gave a sketch of that can be completed with little difficulty.
The latter, well it should certainly be OK for all but the smallest ranks
(if $\Lambda$ has some really bad primes it might accommodate only
a sublattice of $\Lambda_0$, but that's good enough.  If $\Lambda$
has rank only $3$ it gets trickier but even there you can usually do
anything that's not forbidden by a local obstruction, so some $M$ should work
[cont'd]

Comment: ...(up to finite index and variations such as changing $M^4+1$ to $M^4-1$).

Comment: I still don't quite understand how it can be embedded to a given lattice (non-unimodular). For unimodular it's fine, except that I still cannot find a proper reference for an embedding result even in this generality (Morrison quotes Nikulin, but this result is not easy to find in Nikulin's paper).

Comment: One standard approach is to "glue" $\Lambda_0$ to an appropriate rank-1 lattice $M$, obtaining a determinant-1 lattice of rank 3 that contains $\Lambda_0 \oplus M$ with finite index, and is thus isomorphic with $\Lambda$ and contains a copy of $\Lambda_0$.  This can be done for non-unimodular $\Lambda$ too as long as $\Lambda$ is the only lattice in its genus (which is common in the indefinite case).

Comment: Many thanks for the idea, I tried to realize it (determinant 1 is OK, but we want it to be equivalent over ${\mathbb Q}$ with a unimodular lattice). I guess this is just my ignorance, could you point me to appropriate reference?

Comment: Not sure about a canonical reference but there's a lot of material (and references) about indefinite lattices and "gluing" in Conway and Sloane's "SPLAG" = *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't solve the question : it shows that a non-degenerate lattice always contains a primitive rank 2 sublattice with the required property regarding norms ... but the sublattice found is definite. Maybe a modification of the argument would yield the desired result, so I post it.

Without loss of generality we may assume $\Lambda$ is a $3$-dimensional maximal lattice.

Let us write $B_N=\{v\in\Lambda, (v,v)\leq N\}$.

The positive definite case seems easy : for a given $N$, the ball $B_N$ in $\Lambda$ contains only a finite number of vectors, and there certainly exists a $2$-dimensional lattice that doesn't intersect $B_N-\{0\}$.

The lorentzian case is a little subtler since then $B_N$ is not finite anymore. Here is an argument : let us see $\Lambda$ as a lattice in the standard Lorentzian space $\mathbf R^3$ with the form $q(x,y,z)=-x^2+y^2+z^2$ and let us choose the embedding so that the intersection of $\Lambda-\{0\}$ and the hyperplane $P$ defined by the equation $x=0$ is empty. The idea is that the set of vectors of $B_N$ that lie near $P$ is finite, while there are infinitely many hyperplanes of $\Lambda$ that are as near as you want from $P$.

More precisely : let $x_N$ be the minimum of $\vert x\vert $ on $B_N-\{0\}$ (the chosen embedding implies $x_N>0$),  let $B_N'$ be the finite set of vectors of the form $(\pm x_N,y,z)$ in $B_N$ . Let $y_N$ (resp. $z_N$) be the maximum of $y$ (resp. $z$) on $B'_N$.

Finally let $C$ be the set of vectors $(a,b,c)$ satisfying $\vert b\vert \leq \vert \frac{x_N}{3y_N} a\vert $ and $\vert c\vert\leq \vert \frac{x_N}{3z_N} a\vert$. This is a cone with a non-empty interior in the lorentzian space. Thus its intersection with $\Lambda-\{0\}$ is non-empty. Let us pick a vector $v=(a,b,c)$ therein, with $a\neq 0$. Then for a vector $(x,y,z)$ of the ortogonal complement of $v$, the inequalities $\vert y\vert\leq y_N$ and $\vert z\vert\leq z_N$ imply the inequality $x<x_n$. Thus we have $v^\perp\cap B_N=\{0\}$, and $v^\perp\cap\Lambda$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am grateful to Ekaterina Amerik for this remark.

This is not an answer, but in a special case (not the one I need) the solution is known.
In David Morrison's paper 
["On K3 surfaces with large Picard number",](http://math.ucsb.edu/~drm/papers/k3Picard.pdf) Corollary 2.5, it is shown that any
non-degenerate even lattice of appropriate signature and rank admits a primitive embedding to a given unimodular even lattice (I suppose that this is also true for odd lattices, though it's hard to find in the literature). Then we need to take a lattice $N\cdot H$ obtained from any given lattice of signature (1,1) by rescaling with a factor N, and it would be embeddable to a unimodular lattice, solving the problem for unimodular lattices.

Unfortunately, the applications that we have need lattices which are not unimodular.

Comment: In any case this approach must fail in rank $n=3$ because then there are only finitely many $N$ for which a lattice of the form $N\cdot H$ can embed *primitively* into $\Lambda$.

Comment: thanks! anyway, rank $\geq 6$ or $\geq 7$ is a usual assumption in these kind of applications

Comment: But then it feels like the $N \cdot H$ construction or something much like it *does* work even when $\Lambda$ is not unimodular.

Comment: Yes, and this seems to give an answer indeed. I will post it in a couple of days, once I am entirely sure there are no errors

Comment: strike the previous comment, my proof was based on false assumption that any lattice is commeasurable with one which is proportional to unimodular